# Adding children to an existing parent retrieves all existing children

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Like the title says, when I add children to an existing parent, all existing children are retrieved.

Reduced/simplified parent and child models:

```cs
public class ProjectLocalisation
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectImage> Images { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectImage
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    public virtual ProjectLocalisation ProjectLocalisation { get; set; }
}
```

- When creating a new parent with new children, nothing except the
  actual inserts are done on the database.
- When editing an existing parent without adding new children, but
  editing existing children, nothing except the actual updates are done
  on the database.
- When editing an existing parent and adding new children, all existing
  children are retrieved from the database.

Editing an existing parent is done by creating a new instance of the class, setting the primary key(s) and attaching the object. The very moment this line is executed:

```cs
projectLocalisation.Images.Add(image);
```

this query is executed:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[ProjectID] AS [ProjectID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Order] AS [Order], 
[Extent1].[LanguageTag] AS [LanguageTag]
FROM [dbo].[ProjectImages] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[ProjectID] = @EntityKeyValue1) AND ([Extent1].[LanguageTag] = @EntityKeyValue2)',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int,@EntityKeyValue2 nvarchar(128)',@EntityKeyValue1=5,@EntityKeyValue2=N'nl'
```

Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

---

Edit: a workaround seems to be to not make the collection virtual, but I'd rather not use `.Include()` all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like lazy loading. Turn off the lazy loading when you don't need it (or when you don't want it) by calling:

```
dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why EF decides it needs to load all existing data. Disabling lazy loading like that seems to do the trick.

Comment: EF doesn't decide anything. That is a feature of the proxy class generated to support lazy loading (it internally asks EF to load data). The class simply overrides your property and ensures that first access to the navigation property loads all data. Adding to collection is still an access.

Comment: Ah, then lazy loading works slightly different than I thought it did. Thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding images from the other end of the relationship, e.g.

```
db.ProjectImages.Add(new ProjectImage { ProjectLocalisation = localisation, ... }
```